# getting --> Fatal: invalid genesis file: invalid character '/' looking for beginning of object key string

Tags: geth-debugging

I'm just getting started with this.  I started by reading this collection of articles:

```
https://medium.com/m/global-identity?redirectUrl=https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0
```

The syntax they suggested for creating a private blockchain didn't work so I tried every combination I could think of.  Eventually I tried the following:

geth init CustomGenesis.json --datadir .ACPrivateChain

Here's how I configured my install:

- I installed geth in c:\program files\geth.
- I created a genesis.json file and put it in this folder.
- I created a subfolder named 'ACPrivateChain'.

When I run the command, I get:

"Fatal: invalid genesis file: invalid character '/' looking for beginning of object key string"

Can someone help with the right syntax for Windows?

thanks,
clem

Comment: We'll need to see your genesis file... :)

Comment: I just used the one from the tutorial: 

{
    "config": {  
        "chainId": 987, 
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "0x400",
    "gasLimit": "0x8000000",  //set this really high for testing
    "alloc": {}
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following block from your genesis file and try again!

> //set this really high for testing

Comment: It is strange, but comments were causing that error. removing comments resolved errors.